# mqtt.js node - passing qos with a message

Tags: node.js, mqtt, qos

I am using MQTT.js to create a broker for my new app.
For a last few hours I am struggling with passing QoS flag. I can easily pass messageId, dup, retain flags but not QoS.
My code is rather simple, on the client (created with MQTT.js) I do:

```
client.publish({ messageId: 1001, qos: 1, topic: ..., payload: ... });
```

On the server I am doing the following:

```
client.on('publish', function(packet) {
  for ( var key in packet ) {
    util.puts(i+'::'+packet[i]);
  }
});
```

No matter what I set as the QoS on the client I am always getting 0 on the server.
I was expecting this to work out of the box.
Anyone has any experience with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author directly?

Comment: Yes. He was quick with rejecting the pull request but not with answering the question. Found a solution anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem. The author actually acted quite quickly. The solution is in the following pull request: https://github.com/adamvr/MQTT.js/pull/18